# How to print a full size image in c#

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print an image in C#.  It is a full 8.5x11 size tiff created by Adobe Acrobat from a PDF.  When I print it with C# using the code below, it prints correct vertically, but not horizontally, where it is pushed over about a half inch.  I set the origin of the image to 0,0.  Am I missing something?

```
private FileInfo _sourceFile;
    public void Print(FileInfo doc, string printer, int tray)
    {
        _sourceFile = doc;
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer;
        pd.DocumentName = _sourceFile.FullName;
        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(_sourceFile.FullName)) {
            if (img.Width > img.Height) {
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            }
        }
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        foreach (PaperSource ps in pd.PrinterSettings.PaperSources) {
            if (ps.RawKind == tray) {
                pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = ps;
            }
        }
        pd.Print();
    }

    private void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_sourceFile.FullName)) {
            Point loc = new Point(0, 0);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

look at the code from this below for a good example this code is from this link below 
[Print Image in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/431371d0-73a5-4d89-a335-0890c3f87135)

```
        private void PrintImage()
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            pd.OriginAtMargins = false;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);


            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pd;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();

            //pd.Print();
        }

        void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            double cmToUnits = 100 / 2.54;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmIm, 100, 1000, (float)(15 * cmToUnits), (float)(10 * cmToUnits));
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PrintImage();
        }
```

Comment: Jle I will check this I wonder if there is something else that I am not seeing in your code.. this code should work.. I will check back tomorrow and test this again on my end ..

Comment: I'm not sure why I would have to set that.  The image is exactly 8.5 by 11 and looks exactly right when printed, but is moved over about a half inch.  I shouldn't have to resize the image for it to fit (using that overload of drawimage)

Comment: I was under the impression that it was not printing exactly.. sounds like you will need to look at Margins then ..